# pydantic initialize numpy ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, pydantic

how can I initialize a `ndarray` when using pydantic?
This code throws a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

@dataclass
class TestNumpyArray:
    numpyArray: np.ndarray = np.zeros(10)

testNumpyArray = TestNumpyArray()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to provide a [`default_factory`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) to a `Field` declaration.

Note that you can't use arbitrary types in a Pydantic dataclass, so you'll probably want to extend `BaseModel`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import numpy as np

class TestNumpyArray(BaseModel):
    numpyArray: np.ndarray = Field(default_factory=lambda: np.zeros(10))

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

testNumpyArray = TestNumpyArray()
```

You can also use a non-Pydantic dataclass with `dataclasses.field(default_factory=...)`.

Comment: Thanks, not as shiny and easy as I expected but is working.
I wonder: am I better off with using pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass and drop the type hint (: np.ndarray) or using this extended BaseModel and specify the type?

Comment: What are you trying to get out of Pydantic in this case? It's mostly good for validating input and serializing values to a client. For a numpy object, it seems like you're not going to be doing either of those things - so maybe a plain old python `dataclass` is the right choice, since it gives you the default value without needing any additional work.

Comment: The option to get better support in the IDE (pycharm) made me think about adding more type hints to my variables. I also like the generated documentation. But you are right, as I work on a private project (robot control) it's more the interrest in language features than a must have.

Comment: I've found that the builtin `dataclass` has very good Isupport if you annotate the types on your fields - at least with pylance.

Comment: I come here because I want hints from pydantic for Pycharm, too. I suppose its a common request.